# System speaker in GNU/Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I go abroad text or even under any conditions in Emacs works system speaker. How can i turn of it.

I try to write `system-bell off` in /etc/inputrc but it isn't help

Thank you

Comment: And here I am trying to figure out how to get mine to work in Ubuntu 10.04....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq ring-bell-function (lambda () ))
```

That turns off all beeps. I hate beeps of any sort so this works for me, but if you only want to turn off some types of beeps, there are ways to do that too. For example, if you would like to make all the beeps into a visible flash on the screen, you can use:

```
(setq visible-bell t)
```

instead of setting the `ring-bell-function`. Also, check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324457/disable-carbon-emacs-scroll-beep).

Comment: I like this:  `(setq ring-bell-function (lambda () (message "*beep*")))`

Answer (score 1):

Or execute

```
xset b off
```

in a terminal.